# Getting duplicates between two columns and creating a 'duplicated' column with 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such an example dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'pi': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'J']})`

The column lid might have repeated values as shown in the example, the column pi in principle could have either unique values or repeated values among same 'lid' group (see that there is an A for same lid value). What should not happen is that there is different 'pi' values for different 'lid'.

I would like to highlight such cases with a column called say 'duplicates' where there is a '1' when there is a duplicate value of 'pi' for different 'lid' values.

A desired output (I did not think yet about all the possible exception that may arise) is

`df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'pi': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 'duplicates' : [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]})`

This output can be explained as follows, the letter 'A' appears in lid = 1 and lid = 2 so these should be highlighted by a duplicate value = 1. Same thing for the 'D' appearing in lid = 2 and lid = 3. Note that if the 'pi' value repeats only in one lid group then I don't want this to be marked as duplicates

`df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'pi': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 'duplicates' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})`

In case there are multiple same 'pi' in the same group in principle I would be fine highlighting only one case

`df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'pi': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 'duplicates' : [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]})`

note that the third element of 'pi' which is an 'A' is repeated in 'lid' = 1 and an 'A' appears in 'lid' = 2. I would like to highlight only the first 'A' for 'lid' = 1 as in the output.

I've tried several combinations of duplicated(), boolean masks and other things but so far I don't get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for new column filled by number of unique values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) compare if greater like `1`  chained by `&` for bitwise `AND` by another mask by  [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), last cast boolean to `0,1` integers by casting with [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 
                   'pi': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 
                   'duplicates' : [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]})

mask = df.groupby('pi')['lid'].transform('nunique').gt(1) & ~df.duplicated(['lid','pi'])
df['dup'] = mask.astype(int)
print  (df)
    lid pi  duplicates  dup
0     1  A           1    1
1     1  B           0    0
2     1  A           0    0
3     2  A           1    1
4     2  D           1    1
5     2  E           0    0
6     2  F           0    0
7     3  D           1    1
8     3  H           0    0
9     4  I           0    0
10    4  J           0    0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply!  Just to make sure, the column 'duplicates' is something that I don't have and I wish to create. If I try the code you posted with the example of having the third element of 'pi' being an 'A' instead of a 'C'  `df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'pi': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'J']})`
, I get the column 'dup' that contains a '1' corresponding to the duplicated value of 'A' on 'lid' = 1

Comment: @Dima - Not undesarstand, why A  second value is not `1` in `df = pd.DataFrame({'lid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'pi': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'I', 'J']})` ?

Comment: If the second third element of 'pi' would be 'A' it would be correct to mark it as '1' as in your solution. But I would like to keep highlighted only one case of duplicated 'pi' per same value of 'lid'. Thanks